# C# Garbage collection?

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm writing a service right now to automate a couple of my routines. Now I've really only started learning C# within the last month or so I'm still fairly new (but really liking it so far). I've designed my service that it just runs a method on a 5 minute timer which I made via AppSettings, runs a few checks, and organizes a few things if need be and that's it until the next interval.

I quickly realized the initial way I was doing things seems to have a pretty bad memory leak. So I've re-written much of it to embed things in "using" blocks and then disposing those when it's done. The "using" blocks were recommended to me by a developer at work who's been really helpful, but I don't like to bother him too much with my personal projects when he's got work to do.

Currently I'm not *really* having a problem with memory usage, as it's only using about 25Mb of ram, but when it starts, it's only using about 8Mb, and with each polling interval it climbs. But once it reaches that 25Mb threshold, I can see if dip a little lower which I'm assuming is garbage collection doing things, and then it climbs back up to 25Mb, and rinse and repeat. So my applications memory usage is stable, but it just seems higher than it needs to be so I'm curious.

Now if I call GC.Collect manually the memory usage drops to half. I realize this isn't ideal as I've already done some research on this. But now my question really comes down to, is there a some sort of default threshold in .NET when it comes to memory usage and garbage collection? I ask because it would explain what I'm seeing.

I did look at this page on the [Process.MaxWorkingSet Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.maxworkingset(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), but I'm not sure if it would make a difference at all or just potentially cause me problems.

I also tried running a profiler against, but to be honest, this is still new to me and I wasn't entirely clear at what I was looking for.

Comment: What is the question ? I advice you not call GC.Collect manually.

Comment: my question is, is there a some sort of default threshold in .NET when it comes to memory usage and garbage collection?

Comment: My advice: If you sure there is no leak, just don't worry, let the GC do its work whenever it decides to do so.

Comment: You should read this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - in particular the part about generations and conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Conditions for a garbage collection
>
> Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is
>   true:
>
> The system has low physical memory.
>
> **> The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap
>   surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously
>   adjusted as the process runs.**
>
> The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have
>   to call this method, because the garbage collector runs continuously.
>   This method is primarily used for unique situations and testing.
>
> **> When the garbage collector detects that the survival rate is high in a
>   generation, it increases the threshold of allocations for that
>   generation, so the next collection gets a substantial size of
>   reclaimed memory.** The CLR continually balances two priorities: not
>   letting an application's working set get too big and not letting the
>   garbage collection take too much time.

This are quotes from the msdn [GC article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I wonder what *"increases the threshold of allocations for that generation."*. What is meant by *"threshold of allocations for a generation"*? From the rest of the article, newly created objects are put in generation 0 and an object that survives collection in generation 0 is automatically promoted to generation 1, so there's no threshold to speak of. New objects go in generation 0. Survivors of a garbage collection are promoted to the next generation, up to generation 2.